# Issue with how AngularJS functions are called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not sure why, but I have several functions being called 2-4 times as soon as a route loads. Nearly any route I have. It's as if the Controller makes the functions fire although I don't intend for it to be called until an ng-click, etc. There are no $watchers anywhere in my code. I'm using UI-router, and I do assign a controller both in the routing options and in the page itself. And yes I do use an init function to reload the page after certain events. This was still giving me the same issue before adding that in.

I can give a simple example, starting with the HTML being loaded:

```
<a ng-click="finalizarCompra()" class="button btn-ing transition notopmargin fright">Finalizar compra</a>
```

The controller itself:

```
    .controller('CarritoController',
        ['$scope', '$http', 'Carrito',
        function ($scope, $http, Carrito, Session) {

            $scope.initCarrito = function(){
                Carrito.getCart();
            };

            $scope.tieneProductos = function() {
                return Carrito.getCart().length > 0;
            };

            $scope.productos = Carrito.getCart();

            $scope.total = Carrito.totalCarrito();
            $scope.finalizarCompra = Carrito.finalizarCompra();
        }])

// The factory it's using:

.factory('Carrito', ['$http', 'Productos', 'Session', 
            function ($http, Productos, Session){

        var carritoUsuario = [];
        var todosLosProductos = Productos.todos();
        var unProducto = function() {}
            return {

            findBySKU : function(sku) {
                console.log("Finding: " + sku + " from Carrito service findBySKU...");
                return _.find(carritoUsuario, function (producto){
                    return producto.SKU == sku; 
                });
            },

            getProducto : function(id) {
                console.log("Getting: " + id + " from Carrito service getProducto...");
                return Producto.findById(id);
            },

            getCart : function() {
                console.log("Getting cart from Carrito service getCart");
                return carritoUsuario;
            },

            addToCart : function(Prod, cant, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5) {

                unProducto.SKU = "" + Prod.stockid + m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5;
                /*
                s*/
                console.log("Constructed product SKU is: ");
                console.log(unProducto.SKU);


                if(angular.isDefined(this.findBySKU(unProducto.SKU))) {
                    var i = _.findIndex(carritoUsuario, function (prod) {
                        return prod.SKU ==  unProducto.SKU
                    });
                    carritoUsuario[i].Cantidad += unProducto.Cantidad;
                } else {
                    carritoUsuario.push(unProducto);
                }
                console.log(carritoUsuario);
            },


            finalizarCompra: function () {

                var lineas = [];

                    _.forEach(carritoUsuario, function (e) {
                        var obj = {
                                    "stockid" : e.stockid,
                                    "cantidad" : e.Cantidad,
                                    "sku" : e.SKU,
                                    "precio": e.Precio
                                  }
                        lineas.push(obj);
                        }

                    )
                    var calipsoData = {idUser: Session.recallId(), 
                        "lineas":lineas};
                    console.log("Data being sent to calipso is: ");
                    console.log(angular.toJson(calipsoData));

                $http.post('http://restservice', 
                    angular.toJson(calipsoData))
                    .success(function (data){
                        console.log("Alta Pedido exitoso. Data recibido: ");
                        console.log(data);
                    })
                }

        };

    }])
```

I'm sorry if this question seems vague but I'm hoping someone with more Angular experience had a similar experience before. I just shouldn't get more than one console log of anything happened on a page before it's being called.  And in finalizarCompra() it's somehow being called on page load instead of ng-click

UPDATE: changing this:

```
$scope.finalizar = Carrito.finalizarCompra();
```

to this

```
$scope.finalizar = Carrito.finalizarCompra;
```

Did not solve the issue. The fact that it's never being called makes no sense.

[image: Console log spam]

Comment: I don't see it in your code, but providing a controller both in the route definition *and* in the HTML partial is not correct.

Comment: Well I solved the main issue. I had to put the reference to the factory function inside an anymous function. Looks ugly but I suppose it makes sense. Now I just have to figure out why the shopping cart itself loads six times upon page load, because that *is* in an anoymous function already.

Comment: Have you updated your code? Could you remove some of the "noise" (dead code, not relevant code)?

Comment: Where are you calling the function `$scope.initCarrito` from? It sounds like you're doing that in the HTML template somewhere ... which would explain why it gets executed multiple times.  Instead, you probably want to call this function from inside the controller, so that it will be executed only once when the controller is instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your function being executed on page load is because of this line:

```
$scope.finalizarCompra = Carrito.finalizarCompra();
```

Note that the parentheses `()` after the function reference causes the function to be executed. So instead you need to change it to this:

```
$scope.finalizarCompra = Carrito.finalizarCompra;
```

Now you are storing a reference to the function on the scope.

**EDIT**

The other thing that looks suspicious is this function in your controller:

```
$scope.initCarrito = function(){
    Carrito.getCart();
};
```

The function is not used in your controller, so I assume it's being called from the HTML template. Because it's called from the HTML, you'll see this function run every time an Angular digest runs (which is quite often).

It looks like initialization code, and as such you can just run it inside the controller. In fact, you don't necessarily need a function and can just do this:

```
.controller('CarritoController',
        ['$scope', '$http', 'Carrito',
        function ($scope, $http, Carrito) {
            // executes only once, when the controller is created
            Carrito.getCart();

            $scope.tieneProductos = function() {
                return Carrito.getCart().length > 0;
            };

            $scope.productos = Carrito.getCart();

            $scope.total = Carrito.totalCarrito();
            $scope.finalizarCompra = Carrito.finalizarCompra;
        }])
```